# How do I add circuits to a flush mounted panel box?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel

What is the typical method to add circuits to a finished building that has a flush mounted breaker panel when there is no attic or crawl space to drop new runs? I was thinking of surface mounting a sub panel above the main panel and running everything new from there. Or maybe mounting a junction box above the panel that feeds into it, and running my new runs into the junction box and down into the panel.

Comment: The stud cavity where the box is installed is accessible, but there isn't an actual attic or crawl space to run wires for new drops. Everything will have to be ran externally now since the building is finished. Well, unless I was willing to remove the sheetrock, drill holes through the studs, run the new wires and then patch the sheetrock back up, but I honestly don't care about external conduit runs. My main concern was the best method to transition from flush mount to external runs.

Comment: The fact that the building is finished is not a barrier to running additional circuits.  That requires an electrician who specializes in doing that, and has a truck full of tools for doing such work - it's a great deal more like large scale dentistry than electrical work.  I can't believe I just said "hire a professional", and I'm not, I'm saying there are options in that area.

Comment: If you cannot expect to drill through a stud or fix a few feet of Sheetrock repair how do you expect to add a surface mount box conduit ,,,ECT,,, ECT ,,, I don't usually say this and I am a pro but get one !

Comment: Well, first not all walls are sheetrock so eventually I'm going to have to exit out of the walls. Also I know how to drill and cut/patch the walls that are sheetrock but this is an workspace where external emt is completely acceptable. Why take the time to cut/repair the walls, drill through 25-30 studs when running external conduit would work?

Answer (score 1):

#### In the trade it's called fishing walls.

Stud finders, fish tape, electrical tape, jab saw, and a drill will be your trusty friends.

#### Avoid cutting the walls and ceiling with wiremold box and conduit from [Legrand](http://www.cableorganizer.com/wiremold/)